# Printing optimized parameters of a function to fit data

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to fit the logistic equation to some data.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x_data = [2015,2020,2025,2030,2035,2040,2045,2050,2055,2060,2065,2070,2075,2080,2085,2090,2095,2100]
y_data = [958577201,1094365605,1241173739,1399888471,1569045562,1746496103,1930190615,2117730886,2307230067,2496582852,2684012245,2867347398,3044554038,3213530118,3372147573,3519135875,3653665134,3775269513]
x_val = np.array(x_data)
y_val = np.array(y_data)

def fitFunc(x, L, k, c):
    return L/(1+np.exp(-k*(x-c)))
    print(L,k,c)

plt.plot(x_val, y_val, marker='.', markersize=0, linewidth='0.5', color='green')
popt, pcov = curve_fit(fitFunc, x_val, y_val)
plt.plot(x_val, fitFunc(x_val, *popt), color='orange', linestyle='--')
```

I know the plot [the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEYmb.png)

is not scaled properly. But that doesn't matter to me. I want to print the optimized values (L,k,c) so that the logistic curve fits the data best. However, it isn't showing. 
How do I get to see these 3 values after python fits the graph?

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: Just print popt. If you want them in the graph, there is `matplotlib.pyplot.text` to print into the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Your `print(L, k, c)` is located after the `return` of `fitFunc`, so it is never reached. Just move the print one line higher.